# Are there logarithm functions for arbitrary rings?

Tags: ring-theory, entropy, convex-analysis

The logarithm function for $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\log xy = \log x + \log y$ whenever both $\log x$ and $\log y$ are defined.

Are their conditions for a ring $R$ which guarantee the existence of a reasonably large $D \subseteq R$ together with a function $L \colon D \rightarrow D$ that satisfies: if $d_{0}, d_{1} \in D$ then $d_{0}d_{1} \in D$ and $L(d_{0}d_{1}) = L(d_{0}) + L(d_{1})$?

If $0 \in D$ then $L$ is the zero function. I am looking for something not quite so trivial. Since the elements of $D$ are closed under multiplication this might have something to do with rings of fractions. Since ring addition is abelian the elements of $D$ will commute.

[In this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1791) Baez, Fritz, and Leinster use convexity and logarithm functions. If $R$ is an arbitrary ring we can replace $[0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with a subset $C \subseteq R$ that satisfies

1. We have $0, 1 \in C$.
2. For all $c, c_{0}, c_{1} \in C$ we have $c c_{0} + (1 - c) c_{1} \in C$.

The set $C$ will work for the convexity parts of the proofs. There are parts, see corollary 4, where the nonnegative reals are used. We can use $C^{*}$ where $C^{*}$ is the smallest set satisfying

1. We have $C \subseteq C^{*}$.
2. If $c \in C$ and $c^{*}_{0}, c^{*}_{1} \in C^{*}$ then $cc^{*}_{0} +(1 - c)c^{*}_{1} \in C^{*}$.
3. For all $r \in R$; if there exists a $c \in C \smallsetminus \{ 0 \} $ with $cr \in C^{*}$ then $r \in C^{*}$.

With a logarithm function we could create a notion of entropy for a ring where the value of the entropy is an element of the ring.

Comment: Deleted that example. I just wrote some minimal requirments. If something else is needed that's fine.

Comment: Consider the taylor series for $\log(1+x)$. If you can make sense of the coefficients in your ring $R$, then you may have a function with the properties you desire where it converges. If the series is well-defined in $R[[x]]$ then it will have the homomorphism property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the logarithm on [Banach algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra) using the Taylor series whenever it converges, and more generally in any [topological ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) where the Taylor series makes sense and converges. This is already useful for e.g. finite-dimensional real matrices. But IIRC the correct statement is that $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ if everything is defined *and* $a, b$ commute.

There are some obstructions for more general rings, e.g. if $R$ is a commutative ring then a logarithm function needs to give a homomorphism from some subgroup of $R^{\times}$ to some subgroup of $R$ and there may not be a nonzero such homomorphism (consider $R = \mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime).

It's far from clear to me that it's meaningful to generalize entropy much beyond $\mathbb{R}$. All of the motivations I know for defining entropy are pretty specific to the real numbers, and in particular order structure is very important.

Comment: In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211276/is-there-an-alternate-definition-for-z-in-mathbbc-colon-vert-z-vert) there is a method of providing an order for a ring.

Comment: Right, but my point is that the ring-theoretic structure is almost secondary. I think order is the primary structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elaboration of what Qiaochu has indicated in his answer. Let $R$ be a complete topological commutative ring, which is also a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, and whose topology is induced by some ideal $I$ (i.e. the powers $I^k$ are a fundamental system of open neighborhoods of $0$). Then, for every $a \in I$, the sequence defined by $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{a^k}{k}$ is Cauchy, since for $m>n$ we have that $s_m - s_n \in I^{n+1}$, hence converges to some element of $R$, which we might call $\ln(1+a)$. We get a map $\ln : 1+I \to I$.

We can also define an exponential map in the other direction, namely $\exp: I \to 1+I$ mapping $a \mapsto \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{k!}$. The Binomial Theorem and the [Cauchy product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345099) imply $\exp(a+b)=\exp(a) \exp(b)$, so that $\exp$ is a homomorphism of groups $(I,+) \to (1+I,*)$. One can prove that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse to each other, so that in particular $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ (which seems to be quite messy to prove directly, but of course possible) and $(I,+) \cong (1+I,*)$.

In fact, it suffices to check the equations $\exp(\ln(1+a))=1+a$ and $\ln(\exp(a))=a$ in the universal example, the ring of formal power series $R=\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$ (using the continuous homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[[x]] \to R$ defined by $x \mapsto a$). So we only have to check that the coefficients match. But these are the same as in the corresponding well-known equations of analytic power series over $\mathbb{C}$. Direct proofs are also possible, but probably more messy.